# surfaces in $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ cut out by the equation $y^{2}=x^{3}+ax + b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry

I want to show that the solution set of the equation $y^{2}=x^{3}+ax+b$ in $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ is isomorphic to punctured torus.

I have made the following effort, first of all i have tried to find the zeros by putting $x^{3}+ax+b=0$ Since  $x$ is a complex number we have atmost three solution. Now when $x^{3}+ax+b$  is not zero for each value of x we get two values of y .But I am stuck how to proceed from here.

Comment: Do you know Weierstrass $\wp$ function?

Comment: No I don't know about them

Comment: @vikassrivastava Geometrically, if you plot say $y^2 = x^3 - x$ over $\Bbb R^2$, you should be able to convince yourself that you're taking a section of the torus by a hyperplane (so you have two connected components, with one containing the point at infinity, so in that hyperplane section it is unbounded). That should convince you that the zero locus on $\Bbb C$ is a torus. Some work needs to be done to actually prove this though.

Comment: @BalarkaSen I am not able to understand , It would be very helpful if you can help me.